TypeError: supabase.from is not a function
I have a Next.js application, which I am trying to integrate with Supabase.
Below is the initialisation of Supabase
utils/supabase/server.js
'use server'

import { createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function createClient() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name) {
          return cookieStore.get(name)?.value;
        },
        set(name, value, options) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        },
        remove(name, options) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value: "", ...options });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
}


I am trying to invoke the above Supabase instance in my API route
app/api/auth/route.jsx
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';

const checkIfUserExistsInDb = async (email) => {
    const supabase = createClient();
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('Users').select('user_id, user_email, user_authenticators, user_tier').eq('user_email', email)
    // Handle data and error
}

export async function POST(req) {
    const {email} = await req.json()
    const doesUserExist = await checkIfUserExistsInDb(email)
    // Handle my response over here
}

In my server console, I am getting the below error:
 ⨯ TypeError: supabase.from is not a function
    at checkIfUserExistsInDb (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/auth/route.jsx:14:44)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/auth/route.jsx:21:33)

I am unable to fix the issue. For reference, I am trying to follow this blog post from Supabase docs.

In my app/api/auth/route.jsx, I made the below change to fix the issue.
const supabase = createClient(); //before
const supabase = await createClient(); //after
The code was calling createClient without await. createClient is an asynchronous function, and without await, the function wouldn't return the actual Supabase client instance immediately. Instead, it would return a Promise that resolves to the client later. Adding await ensures that the code waits for the Promise returned by createClient to resolve before continuing. This guarantees that the supabase object is a fully initialized Supabase client when used inside the function.

I recently ran into this same issue after I installed next-sanity. Though before, const supabase = createClient(); worked perfectly fine for me. But after, I needed to update it to const supabase = await createClient();. Any idea why Supabase's docs don't use async/await?

await made it work for me thanks!
